# Not able use lftp commands running from shellscript

Tags: shell, lftp

I'm using set of commands from a shellscript. First command is running fine but it is moving to lftp command prompt and expecting manual input instead of running commands from  shelscript. Following are the commands i'm using

```
lftp -e "$HOST"
lftp -u "$USER,$PWD" 
lftp -e "cd /inbox"
put $file
bye
```

Please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lower-case variable names to avoid conflicts with local environment variables or shell-builtins (`$USER` and `$PWD` are both builtins, so you shouldn't be setting them yourself):

```
lftp \
  -e "cd /inbox; put $file" \
  -u "$user,$pwd" \
  "$host"
```

The point, here, is invoking `lftp` **only once**, and passing all the necessary commands to that single invocation.