# ksh script to send .jpg to remote server through ftp script

Tags: shell

Hello just created a ksh script to ftp .jpg image to a remote server but the images are showing in bad qulity when I send them with the script is there a line I should fix to not alterate the image a deliver the image to the remote server like the original please help, should I add the bin line?

```
cp -r /path/dir/*.jpg /path/dir
cp -r /path/dir/*.JPG /path/dirREMOTE
USER='xxx'
PASSWORD=xxx'
source_dir='cd /path/images/'
target_dir='cd /images'
ftp -n xxx.xx.xxx.xx <<_FTP
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWORD
lcd /xxx/xxx/
cd /xxx
mput *.jpg
bye
_FTP
/home/test_scripts/test_script9.sh
/home/test_scripts/test_script7.sh
exit
enter code here
```

Comment: now they not even showing it says file corrupted, should I add the bin just above the lcd line?

Comment: Can you install/use lftp? Much easier to script, and does binary transfers out-of-the-box by default.

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909434/not-able-use-lftp-commands-running-from-shellscript

Comment: ...or, for a simple one-liner example: `lftp -u "$user:$password" ftp://host -e 'put localfile -o /path/to/dest' </dev/null`

Comment: Note the use of **lower-case** variable names; all-uppercase `$USER` is reserved. Using lower-case names for your own variables avoids conflicts, and is suggested by the POSIX standard; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Also, note that USER is **specifically** named in the above specification as a well-known variable name one should avoid overwriting.

Comment: thanks very much for the help it seems the bin above the lcd line helped but next time or maybe later today I will use that onse simple line im struggling a little bitn with scripting